# adding two images with different types with Matlab's imadd function

Tags: matlab, double, addition, complex-data-types

How can I add two matrices, one of complex doubles and the other just doubles, using the `imadd` function in Matlab?

```
%tpye of img1 is double and img2 is complex double
img=imadd(img1,img2);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why `img=img1+img2` is not suitable for you?

Comment: Not terribly familiar with image processing but from the documentation it looks like `imadd` is just matrix addition that truncates any values `> 255`, which you can do manually after normal matrix addition.

Comment: for image enhancement img1 is original image and img2 is sharpened image after specific process.

Comment: What does `imadd` do to an image of type double that simply adding the two matrices doesn't do? What more are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If normalization Matrix useful information is lost.

Comment: Please suggest an alternative to imadd to this topic That do not need to normalization matrix.

Comment: @Mohammad It sounds to me that you are trying to sharpen an image by high pass filtering the image, and adding the results on top of the original image.  Why are the sharpened results *complex-valued*? Did you do the sharpening in the Fourier domain?  If that's the case, take the **inverse**, then add the results in spatial domain. You are comparing apples with oranges together.  Don't.  Have you ever heard of the XY problem?  That's what's going on right now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @rayryeng  The reason of it is complex double that img2 is output of inverse wavelet transform.

Comment: @Mohammad You probably have residual imaginary components, extract only the real components then add them together: `img = img1 + real(img2);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are having trouble displaying images after adding them together. When you use `imshow(img)` matlab always looks at the type of `img` when it sees its a double it maps `0=black 1>=white` so a lot of information gets clipped.

After you add the images together you should scale them again so the values are between 0 and 1. Here is a function that will normalize the array

```
function normalized_arr = NormalizeArray(inp_arr)
% normalized_im = NormalizeArray(inp_arr) takes an input array of any size
%       and normalizes all the values so the result is an array with all
%       values between 0 and 1 inclusive

    %finds the smallest value in the current array
    min_val = min(inp_arr(:));

    %finds the largest value in the current array
    max_val = max(inp_arr(:));

    %finds the scale factor so that all values are between 0 and 1
    scale_factor = 1 / (max_val - min_val);

    %removes offset from image, so the minimum value will be 0
    normalized_arr = inp_arr - min_val;

    %normalization
    normalized_arr = normalized_arr .* scale_factor;
end
```

You would use it in your code like this

```
img = img1+img2;
norm_img = NormalizeArray(img);
imshow(norm_img);
```

Comment: We haven't written an answer because one of the images is complex-valued.  Adding a real image and a "complex" image doesn't really make sense, which is why we've been asking the OP above in the comments thread.  That being said, what you have said is perfectly valid... given that both of the images are of the same type.

Comment: You are correct. I read it as img1 __AND__ img2 were both complex double. I figured he was just working in Fourier domain

Comment: Oh for sure.  If both were complex, then this would still work... both of them aren't the same type, which has all made us very confused lol.

Comment: Thank you all
I just looking for a way that adding two image, complex double and double.without any lossless method.

Comment: @Mohammad You can't.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mohammad I like your sense of humour.... but if you could really do it, you wouldn't be asking us how to do it now... would you?